# jQuery multiple inputs and checking length

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to combine 4 input fields into a jQuery function so that it checks each input as its keyup'd and when all the boxes reaches a length of 4 then the list item changes to acknowledge all fields are full

***HTML***

```
<div class="cardNumber">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn1" id="ccn1">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn2" id="ccn2">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn3" id="ccn3">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" name="ccn4" id="ccn4">
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="checkNumber">Card Number</li>
</ul>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(".cardNumber input[name=ccn1], .cardNumber input[name=ccn2], .cardNumber input[name=ccn3], .cardNumber input[name=ccn4]").keyup(function() {
    $(".cardNumber input[name=ccn1], .cardNumber input[name=ccn2], .cardNumber input[name=ccn3], .cardNumber input[name=ccn4]").each(function() {
        if ($(".cardNumber input[name=ccn1], .cardNumber input[name=ccn2], .cardNumber input[name=ccn3], .cardNumber input[name=ccn4]").length >= '4') {
            $("li.checkNumber").addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fz4wF/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(':input[name^=ccn]').keyup(function() {
    var check = $(':input[name^=ccn]').filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length < 4;
    }).length === 0;

    $("li.checkNumber").toggleClass("checked",check);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d7BqH/1/)**

Comment: I went with this answer but edited it to be the following

[CODE]
$(':input[name^=ccn]').keyup(function() {
    var check = $(':input[name^=ccn]').filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length < 4;
    }).length === 0;

    if (check) {
     $("li.checkNumber").addClass("checked");
    } else {
     $("li.checkNumber").removeClass("checked");
    }
});
[/CODE]

Comment: @DonaldSutherland, toggleClass with the seconds parameter (check) does what your if else statement does. Right?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/fz4wF/19/

```
$(".cardNumber input").keyup(function(){    
    var allfilled = true;
    $(".cardNumber input").each(function() {
        if($(this).val().length < 4) {
            allfilled =false;
            return false;
        }
    });  

    $("li.checkNumber").toggleClass("checked",allfilled);    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fz4wF/14/) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way is this: http://jsfiddle.net/fz4wF/28/
not the best.